# Query Custom WordPress/buddyPress Table (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, buddypress

I have been looking around and trying different things for a while and no luck.

Scenario: I have WordPress/BuddyPress and I added in a few new tables to the database through phpMyAdmin. I cannot run a successful query to them, yet I can to all the original tables. I have tried many things, this is my most recent try, still not working:

```
$b1_exc = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM memberbadge
WHERE 1") );
```

I would really appreciate a solution to **add custom tables and be able to query them.**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a prefix problem. 
Try:

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}memberbadge") );
```

If you really need a `WHERE` clause and the variable comes from user input, then use `prepare`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Between this and finding out that capitalization matters in my table name it is now working! :)

Answer (score 1):

**As of 3.5, wpdb::prepare() enforces a minimum of 2 arguments.**

This is the correct syntax for wpdb::prepare(), use this.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM memberbadge WHERE %d", 1) );
```